# Ping does not work with BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void backworker_PING_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bool pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    try
    {
        PingReply reply = pinger.Send(MainWindow.GlobalVar.global_ip);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
             pingable = true;
        }
        else
        {
             pingable = false;
        }
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }
    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("...");
    if (pingable == true)
    {
        this.pingtxt.Content = MainWindow.GlobalVar.global_ip + " is Ping able.";
    }
    else
    {
        this.pingtxt.Content = @"[!]" + MainWindow.GlobalVar.global_ip + " is unPingable.";
    }
}
```

> dowork is run every 3 second.
>
> MainWindow.GlobalVar.global_ip is a string and always "127.0.0.1"
>
> and
>
> pingtxt was not set context. what the problem is it?

```
<Label x:Name="pingtxt" Content="***?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="650,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Label.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8F8F8F" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Label.Foreground>
            <Label.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="2" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </Label.Effect>
        </Label>
```

> pingtxt details

Comment: Is `pingtxt` a `Button` or more generically a `ContentControl` on the UI?

Comment: And throws a `System.InvalidOperationException`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only modify the UI from the UI thread.

Use [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void backworker_PING_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bool pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    try
    {
        PingReply reply = pinger.Send(MainWindow.GlobalVar.global_ip);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            pingable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pingable = false;
        }
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }
    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("...");
    if (pingable == true)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { pingtxt.Content = MainWindow.GlobalVar.global_ip + " is Ping able."; }));
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { pingtxt.Content = MainWindow.GlobalVar.global_ip + " is unPingable."; }));
    }
}
```

I tested, and this works for me.

Comment: thx. invoke it works.